# Button Link library in Bintray to jCenter not available

Tags: android, bintray, jcenter

Could you please help me how to Link Bintray Library to jCenter.

I research a lot and found that we have to be an OSS or Premium account to Update. I also create an Issue on https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/OSSRH-36683 and also get a response.

I also config the OSS account link into bintray account but couldn't see Link To jCenter button.

Library URL: https://bintray.com/khangtran/maven/preferences-helper

Below a screenshot, could you please take a look and guide me what wrong with my configuration.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found the problem is my Account is Trial Account, so I delete it and re-create it with the ["oss](https://bintray.com/signup/oss)" and then setups project the same with the previous and I can add it to jCenter.